# PHP help multi step form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, form-submit

I am creating a multi-step form, and I am struggling to pass around the ID's to each step of the form, below is my code

```
    function add_career() {
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if($this->input->post('career_set') == 'Save') {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('career_name', 'Career name', 'required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('career_desc', 'Career description', 'required|max_length[3000]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('useful_info', 'Useful Information', 'max_length[1000]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('useful_links', 'Useful Links', 'max_length[1000]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
               $this->template->build('admin/add_career'); 
            } else {
               if($this->input->post('degree_needed')) {
                   $degree_needed = 'Yes';
               } else {
                   $degree_needed = 'No';
               }

               $this->load->model('careers');
               $insertCareer = $this->careers->save(
                 $this->input->post('career_name'),
                 $this->input->post('career_desc'),
                 $degree_needed,
                 $this->input->post('useful_info'),
                 $this->input->post('useful_links')
               );

                   //save the data in the session, so we can to it if need be


                $this->career_id = $this->db->insert_id;
                $this->session->set_userdata($insertCareer);
                //$this->firephp->log($this->session->userdata($this->career_id, 'Career ID'));        
               }
        }

        $this->career_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        if($this->input->post('salary_set') == 'Save') {

                $this->firephp->log($this->career_id);
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('basic_salary', 'Basic salary', 'required|max_length[12]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('trained_salary', 'Fully trained salary', 'required|max_length[12]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('progressed_salary', 'Progressing onto salary', 'required|max_length[12]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('average_salary', 'Average salary', 'required|max_length[12]');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                        $this->template->build('admin/add_career'); 
                } else {
                    $this->load->model('salaries');
                    $insertSalary = $this->salaries->save(
                        $this->input->post('basic_salary'),
                        $this->input->post('trained_salary'),
                        $this->input->post('progressed_salary'),
                        $this->input->post('average_salary'),
                        $this->career_id
                    );

                $this->session->set_userdata($insertSalary);
                $this->firephp->log($insertSalary);    
                }
        }

        if($this->input->post('course_grades_set') == 'Save') {
            //first off we need to save the grade details

            $this->load->model('grades');
            $this->load->model('course');
            $this->firephp->log(count($_POST['grade_desc']));

            foreach ($_POST['grade_desc'] as $k => $v) {
                $this->firephp->log($v, 'Looped Results');
                $insertGrade = $this->grades->save($v, $this->session->userdata('career_id'));
                // theorertically we should be able to save the assicated course at the same time using $k
                $insertCourse = $this->course->save(
                    $_POST['course_type'][$k],
                    $_POST['course_names'][$k], 
                    $_POST['course_links'][$k],
                    $this->db->insert_id()
                );
                $this->firephp->log($insertGrade, $k);
                $this->firephp->log($insertCourse, $k);
            }
            //$insertGrades = $this->grades->save()
            //);
        }




   $this->template->build('admin/add_career', $data);
}
```

I need to get the last inserted id from the section that saves the career, and pass it to the next step that saves the salary details, at the moment, all I get is a null variable. The var i am is `$this->career_id`;

If anyone can explain how I can get the last inserted id into the last section of the form.

Many thanks

Comment: I recommend you distill the code you provided to only parts directly related to the question you are asking.  You may get a better or faster answer if the question is clearer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suppose that you use $this->db->insert_id to retrieve the last inserted id in the database. You use 2 different calls to get the last insert id.
The first one :

$this->career_id = $this->db->insert_id;

The second one:

$this->career_id = $this->db->insert_id();

I suggest you use the session to retrieve the carrer id, on the second call.

Also, what does the save method returns (for all models)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable `$this->db` is not available in this function/class.

If you will log the output of `$this->db->insert_id();` in the class `careers`, function `save`, then you'll get the right ID. I'm pretty sure this function will work in your `Model`